# Changing the dimension of jsPlumb canvas

Tags: jsplumb

I was wondering if and where I can change the dimension of the canvas in jsPlumb, the place where all my draggable elements are?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple jQuery to change the dimensions of any DOM element.

jsPlumb isn't really a canvas thing, it creates DOM objects to represent the graph.

```
$("#jsPlumbContainer").css('width','+=100');
$("#jsPlumbContainer").css('height','+=100');
```